# Installing DPMS extension on Ubuntu?

Tags: monitor

**Accidentally logged in on Ubuntu on Wayland which caused DPMS not to be enabled. My bad. **

I need to run a script in JS: exec('xset dpms force off', null);

I'm running Ubuntu 18.10 and it doesn't have DPMS enabled. Is there a way to install/enable it? Can't seem to find anything on it.

Thanks!

Comment: It should just be `xset dpms` to enable it and `xset -dpms` to disable.  Then you can run `xset -q | awk '/DPMS is/ {print $NF}'` to see if it is enabled or disabled.

Comment: @Terrance If I write xset dpms it returns "server does not have extension for dpms option". xset -q returns a lot of stuff and "DPMS (Energy Star): Server does not have the DPMS Extension". Any idea of how I can install it?

Comment: I was logged in on Ubuntu on Wayland. That was my problem 

Comment: Ah, I don't use Wayland as I only use Xubuntu (Xfce4) so I wasn't thinking that.  Glad you figured it out.  =)

Answer (score 1):

I was logged in to Ubuntu on Wayland which didn't have DPMS enabled or installed. Just logged in to regular Ubuntu and everything worked.

@Terrance did come up with a solution though: sudo apt install libxcb-dpms0*

Comment: Hmm. Had hoped that might bring dpms back on Debian Buster. No such luck,